# Why can $ be matched twice, giving an additional empty match?

Tags: regex

I was trying out - for fun - a pattern to match comma separated input:

```
(?:(?:\"(.*?)\")|(.*?))(?:[,]|$)
```

which should match anything between quotation marks, or anything without quotation marks followed by a comma or end of input.

And matching (using find):

```
Country,"Name1 and Name2, Province of",City
```

Tested using the following Java code:

```java
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:(?:\"(.*?)\")|(.*?))(?:[,]|$)");
Matcher m = p.matcher("Country,\"Name1 and Name2, Province of\",City");
while (m.find()) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= m.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.printf("Group(%d) : %s%n", i, m.group(i));
    }
}
```

Which generates the following output:

```
Group(0) : Country,
Group(1) : null
Group(2) : Country
Group(0) : "Name1 and Name2, Province of",
Group(1) : Name1 and Name2, Province of
Group(2) : null
Group(0) : City
Group(1) : null
Group(2) : City
Group(0) : 
Group(1) : null
Group(2) :
```

I'm a bit flabbergasted about the final match, which is empty. It seems to me that `City` can only be matched if `$` is matched, and that therefore the `find()` should end because the full input was matched. Still, there is an empty match added to the list.

**Why** is that final empty match reported? Is `$` not considered to be part of a match, indicating that matching should stop?

---

Please note that I am **not** looking for alternate solutions, I've already found a few. I'm certainly not looking for solutions that propose `.+?` that also disallow empty strings within commas.

I've also tried the regexp and input in an online tool, and I got the same result, so I'm pretty sure that this is not specific to Java (in case you are missing the tag).

Making the final non-capturing group a capturing group didn't help, by the way (which seems logical, capturing has nothing to do with greediness).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the extra match due to the [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) which will try all options. The anchor `$` is an assertion which [asserts](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-anchors.html#anywhere) the end of the line in the alternation.

In your patten you use `(.*?)` which will match any character 0+ times which will also settle for 0 matches as it is non greedy. Afterwards there is an alternation which will match either a comma or assert the end of the string `(?:[,]|$)`

After having `.*?$` matched `City` the position is at the end of the string. The alternation tries if it can match another time, which it can because the position at the end of the string can be matched by 0 chars and asserting the end of the string.

Comment: That's more like the answers I'm looking for. However, I don't *completely* get it yet. That last match must be the end of the input, and as it is used in search, doesn't that mean that it is **not** an alternation of `City`? Wouldn't be `ity` also be an alternation etc.? And why only for that match?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes The alternation matches 2 types of matches, the first from `"` until the closest `"` and the other 0+ chars non greedy. What follows after one of those matches must be either a comma or assert the end of the string. This part of the alternation `|(.*?)` will [capture](https://regex101.com/r/TEnYxE/1) `Country` because it is followed by a comma and `City` because it matches the end of string assertion afterwards. See the [groups](https://regex101.com/r/PyE7mb/1) when the order is reversed. If there was `ity` instead of City then that would also be captured in group 2.